# Need help in recognizing the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $x,y$ & $z$ are the elements of a group such that $xyz=1$ then which of the following is true

1).$yzx=1$

2).$yxz=1$

3).$zxy=1$

4).$zyx=1$

Not able to recognize the nature of group.Don't know what $1$ is here as the group  is not specified.

Comment: Obviously the group operation is multiplicative. So, by default, $1$ is the neutral element. Hmm.
$$x^{-1}(xyz)x=yzx.$$ so...

Comment: As others have pointed out, 1) and 3) are both true. But to answer the question completely, you would need to find examples of groups $G$ and elements $x,y,z \in G$ such that 2) and 4) do not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $yzx=x^{-1}\cdot xyz \cdot x= x^{-1}\cdot 1 \cdot x =1$

Answer (score 1):

As a different way of thinking about it, $xyz=1$, hence $yz=x^{-1}$, so $yzx=1$. Similarly you can show 3). is true.